# Call a function in R Script from a Batch file

Tags: r, windows, function, batch-file, command-line

I've a batch file that calls R script. It works fine. I need to know how Can I Call a function in R Script from that Batch file in windows? How to call this Function with parameters:

```
PNLCalcMultipleDatesClient("2010-10-03", "2010-10-05", "XYZ")
```

This command line works but it doesn't have Function call that is in R Script. Can you please help me to modify this command line in Windows and call above function ?

```
"\\C1PRDTLS01.axinc.com\Dev\RiskClient\inputCData\PNLCalculation\R\R-3.1.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore "\\C1PRDTLS01.axinc.com\Dev\RiskClient\inputCData\PNLCalculation\RScript\RadarPNLTimeseries.R"
```

Here is the R Script:

```
PNLCalcMultipleDatesClient("2010-10-03", "2010-10-05", "Dunavant")

PNLCalcMultipleDatesClient <- function(begindate, enddate, Client)
{
  # Do some operation here....
  .....
  ......

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. Here is the Rscript that i have, i tend to save them as txt itself.

```
## Rscript: Passing arguments to the Rscripts likes args[i] 
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
print(1:args[1])
df=data.frame(1:args[1])
write.csv(df, args[2])
```

Then your batch file would look like this. Then you feed those arguments either directly to a cmd or create a batch file out of it.

```
echo off
Rscript rparam.txt 1000 out.csv
```

For your case, your Rscript(R_with_par.R) would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
x1=args[1]
x2=args[2]
x3=args[3]
PNLCalcMultipleDatesClient <- function(begindate, enddate, Client)
{
    # Do some operation here....
    .....
    ......

}

PNLCalcMultipleDatesClient(as.Date(x1), as.Date(x2), as.character(x3))
```

And your CMD command would be:

```
Rscript R_with_par.R 2010-10-03 2010-10-05 Dunavant
```

You have to make sure that parameters that you pass are in format required by R. Give the path of the R script if you are not in the same directory. Also `Rscript` is far better choice than `R CMD`.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to call a R script. My question was how to call a function in the R script from command line. Is there any way to do it? or any main function or something that exist in R which is called automatically like Java or C# ?

Comment: I dont think you can call a r function from cmd. You need to put that function in R script and then call that.

Comment: In that case, how to pass arguments to that function? Let's say in my R Script I've few functions, functionA(arg1, arg2), functionB(arg1, arg2) etc. If I pass those arguments from cmd, how R script will understand which function to pass ?

Comment: @see my edits. i am passing args[1], args[2] from the cmd. you have to give different arguments for different function i suppose. Also R doesnt have a main class that you need to call before call your other classes.

Comment: I understand but as I'm new to R I'm not able to follow you completely. I've modified my first post and added the R Script that I've. Can you please help me to modify the R script and pass three parameters like the way you're recommending ?

Comment: Great. I got the idea. Only change I made at my end is rather than converting the arguments I kept it as it is, something like this - PNLCalcMultipleDatesClient(x1, x2, x3). It works perfectly. If you want to change that in your comment for future reference would be 100% perfect solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I think if the parameters(x1,x2,..) are in proper format then one can call function directly.Otherwise it is safe to put those kind of checks when calling in function.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create R Function:

   squared <- function(number) {
   sqred <- number^2
   cat(sqred)
   }

squared(as.integer(commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)))

2. Run R script from command prompt: (Your path could be different)

   C:R/bin/RScript.exe" "C:/Rscript/command_line.R" 100
   Note: First argument is path of Rscript.exe, Second Argument is path of your R script and third argument is function argument.